# How do i download patches on Trainz Simulator 2010

Tags: trainz-2010

It says my version is out of date and that I can download the patches on the forums so I click the link and it comes up with the downloads available. When I try to download the patch it opens up a window and does nothing. What should I do?

Comment: have you bought it on steam, or do you have the dvd?

Comment: I bought it off Amazon. i didnt download it or anything. I assume it was you who changed tags. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patches for Trainz 2010 can be found on the [official N3V page](http://www.auran.com/servicepacks/default.php#TS2010).

You need to find what version you are currently running, and then download and install patches in sequence to bring your build numbers up. So, if your build is currently `41491` (the original retail release), you'd need to download and run the following files in order:

- http://dgdl.auran.com/TS2010Download/41491_to_41615.exe
- http://download.ts2009.com/patch/41615_to_42203.exe
- http://download.ts2009.com/patch/42203_to_43434.exe
- http://download.ts2009.com/patch/43434_to_44088.exe
- http://download.ts2009.com/patch/44088_to_49933.exe

You should then be able to "autopatch" to v. `46170` from within the initial game screen. Then apply the following patch:

- http://download.ts2009.com/patch/46170_to_49938.exe

And that should make you up-to-date for Trainz 2010.

The web servers are a bit slow to respond when clicking on these links, but you should be able to click them, then select "save" and run them.

This only works for retail versions of Trainz, or those purchased directly from N3V (Auran). Games purchased on Steam or other digital distribution means are not supported by N3V.

Comment: my build is 42203 so should i download from the 3rd download or what.

Comment: yes, start from the `42203_to_43434` download

Comment: This could take some time